# Best way to send an image as json object from sql in C#

Tags: c#, sql, json

I am retrieving an image as byte array in C#. I want to know the best possible way to sent this image as json. This code currently return it as a memorystream.

```
              var note = reader["Note"].ToString();
              var price =  (decimal)reader["Price"];                 

              //try this
              byte[] byteimage = (byte[])reader["Image"];
              using (Image pngimage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(byteimage)))
              {
               CakesList.Add(new CakesDetails(cakeid, cakename, type, category, description, ingredients, gender, note, price, pngimage));
              }                  
          }
        sqlConnection.Close();
        }catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            ex.StackTrace.ToString();
        }
        return CakesList;
```

I would like to maybe achieve something like this.

```
[{
        "title": "Dawn of the Planet of the Apes",
        **"image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg",**
        "rating": 8.3,
        "releaseYear": 2014,
        "genre": ["Action", "Drama", "Sci-Fi"]
    },
    {
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well that's not sending an image, that's sending the URL for an image. You need to distinguish between "the bytes that make up the image" and "a URL you can use to get at the image". It's not really clear which you have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't want to actually *send* the image as JSON, but you want to send the name of the image. To do that, do the following:

1. Document how the receiver of the JSON data can download an image named "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg" (well, that would be kind of obvious since it is a URL, still should be documented).
2. Send that URL as part of your JSON.
3. Do whatever is needed so that someone trying to download that image will get it. This most likely involves storing your byte array somewhere as a file, probably under the path "json/movies/1.jpg".

That said, what you are saying is weird. Why would you be retrieving the image if all you want to do is tell someone else where it is? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks so much and excuse my wording there...no wonder I struggled to get answers in google. Thanks once again